# Sum of all divisors of the first $n$ positive integers.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, summation, prime-numbers

Yesterday I was going through [Möbius Function](https://math.berkeley.edu/~stankova/MathCircle/Multiplicative.pdf) notes, and found that 
writing $n = p_{1}^{\alpha_1}p_{2}^{\alpha_2}\cdots p_{r}^{\alpha_r}$,
the sum of all divisors can be written as.
$$
e(n) = \prod_{i = 1}^r \frac{p_{i}^{(\alpha_i + 1)}-1}{p_i - 1}.
$$
So I decided to calculate my own sum.
$$
S(n) = \sum_{i = 1}^r \frac{p_{i}^{(\alpha_i + 1)}-1}{p_i - 1},
$$
which is simple by the looks of it. To make it even more hard, I added an additional sum.
$$
F(n) = \sum_{m = 1}^n S(m)
$$
Is there a shortform to calculate this $F(n)$ easily for large values of n as well?

Comment: I was looking if there is any way this can be calculated without going through every m. using some convolution etc? @Servaes

Answer (score 2):

A slightly easier to compute expression for $F(n)$ is
$$F(n)=\sum_{d=1}^nd\Big\lfloor\frac{n}{d}\Big\rfloor.$$
One way to see this, is to note that if $d$ is a divisor of $S(m)$ and $m\leq n$, then $d\leq n$. And every positive integer $d\leq n$ is summed precisely once for each multiple of $d$ up to $n$, so $\lfloor\tfrac nd\rfloor$ times.

Comment: here in your sum d means the divisor or all the numbers from 1 to n?

Comment: @Shagun The sum over $d$ ranges over all integers from $1$ to $n$; I have labeled it $d$ to show how it relates to the original sum.

Comment: It did some help. but still we need to calculate for all d.

Comment: @Shagun Yes, but now you no longer need to factor every integer up to $n$. I doubt you will find a more easily computable closed form than this. My machine compute $F(10^8)$ in about $2$ seconds using this expression directly.

Comment: Yes but I need upto $10^{18}$ so This did help but not as much.

Comment: What if we split the floor to n / d and frational part can we simplify even further?

Comment: @Servaer what do u say about that?